# Android date and time

Tags: android, date

I want to display current date and time using calendar.my code is

```
    LinearLayout lview=new LinearLayout(this);
    myText=new TextView(this);
    strText=new TextView(this);


    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    int seconds=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    myText.setText("Your current seconds are:");
    strText.setText(seconds);

     lview.addView(strText);
     lview.addView(myText);

    setContentView(lview);
```

but it shows the app unfortunately stops working without displaying date..

Comment: You should get into the habit of posting Logcat output when you have an error or crash that you cannot solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setting Layout Paramaters for each view will solve your problem**

```
lview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));\\Linear Layout
strText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); \\TextView
myText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));\\TextView
```